# Disabling textbox on change of drop down list even after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a dropdown and text box in my application.Based on the selection of items in dropdown I need to disable the textbox. I am using to achieve this using JavaScript.But on the pressing refresh the controls are going to the original modes because the page is reloading.
I need to keep the textbox disabled even after the refresh of the page.
Can I achieve that functionality.
**My JavaScript**

```
function disable(){
    var zone = $("#txtzone").val();
    var eqtype= $("#txtetype").val();           
    if(eqtype=='Virtual'){
        document.getElementById('txtsno').value='Virtual';
        document.getElementById('txthesx').disabled=false;

        document.getElementById('txtwstdt').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('txtwendt').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('txtemnt').disabled=true;       
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txtsno').value='';
        document.getElementById('txthesx').disabled=true;               
        document.getElementById('txtwstdt').disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('txtwendt').disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('txtemnt').disabled=false;
    }   
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: How about using a cookie or localStorage for a flag which indicates if the textbox should be enabled or not?

Comment: What is the platform of the application, is it a plain HTML or you are using some other platforms like JSP or PHP ...

Comment: hi Shahe I am using PHP in this scenario

Comment: so you can store the value of the dropdown in your PHP

Comment: can u allobarat you explanation Shahe i didnt get what you are saying

Comment: can you show me your html and PHP